# Create additional rows for date range with latest available information using sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which looks like this:

[image]

Here, I have a item A with rate information on certain days. How can I populate new rows in same table with date range from 01/01/2020 to 01/30/2020 and every row will contain latest available next **rate**.

For example,

```
`01/01/2020 to 01/10/2020 will have rate = 10`
`01/11/2020 to 01/15/2020 will have rate = 13`
`01/16/2020 to 01/25/2020 will have rate = 15`
`01/26/2020 to 01/30/2020 will have rate = 15`
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Create another table where you store the start_date, end_date and rate values. JOIN.

Comment: I am using postgress database